# How to show above/below icon for winform treeview drag drop

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, treeview

I would like to highlight(show icon) at drop target location.Something similar to third party controls which show an icon above or below the target node, to show preview for destination location.

[image: A sample screenshot is attached, where it show a line below the target node:]

Is there any example or idea how it can be done in winform treeview?

Comment: Outlook doesn't use standard controls, everything is custom drawn.  One of those luxuries you can afford when you have a hundred thousand employees.  Look at component vendors for something similar.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It is not about outlook. I am using a standard windows form treeview control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find exactly what I was looking for, means was not able to show the icons above or below the target node however, I managed to allow user to add nodes above or below the target node by using the following solution:

Treeview drop event provide info whether drop was on image or text part of target node which can be used to decided whether to add dropped node above or below.

```
Dim hTest As TreeViewHitTestInfo
Private Sub TreeView1_DragOver(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.DragOver

     Dim pt As Point = CType(sender, TreeView).PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
     hTest = TreeView1.HitTest(pt)

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.DragDrop

    If hTest IsNot Nothing AndAlso hTest.Location = TreeViewHitTestLocations.Image Then
    'Add Above
    Else
    'Add Below
    End If

End Sub
```